# Why is LRU cache not implemented using doubly linked list with just two nodes? Do we even need double linked list?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays, hash-tables, linked-lists

I don't understand why do we need to have more than two nodes in doubly linked list when all we need to maintain is the most recent and least recently accessed nodes.

I was going through solutions for LRU Cache and it seems that all solutions seem to ignore this. The linked list's size keeps increasing.

Can we do this with just two nodes?

Can we do it without doubly linked list and still without increasing the time and space complexity? (unlike with arrays where you will have to shift)

I tried to write solution where there are only two nodes at max at any point in time. But it didn't work.
Not sure what went wrong. Gave it several tries and then gave up.

**Solution with no cap on no. of nodes:**

```
import java.util.*;


class Program {
  static class LRUCache {
        HashMap<String,DoublyLinkedListNode> cache = new HashMap<String,DoublyLinkedListNode>();
        DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
    int maxSize;
        int currentSize = 0;
    public LRUCache(int maxSize) {
      this.maxSize = maxSize > 1 ? maxSize : 1;
    }

    public void insertKeyValuePair(String key, int value) {
      if(!cache.containsKey(key)){
                if(currentSize < maxSize){                  
                    currentSize++;
                } else{                 
                    evictLastUsedKey();                 
                }
                cache.put(key,new DoublyLinkedListNode(key,value));
            } else {
                replaceKey(key,value);
            }
            setMostRecent(cache.get(key));
    }

        
        public void setMostRecent(DoublyLinkedListNode node){
            list.setHead(node);
        }

    public LRUResult getValueFromKey(String key) {          
            if(!cache.containsKey(key)) return new LRUResult(false,-1);
            setMostRecent(cache.get(key));
      return new LRUResult(true,cache.get(key).value);
    }

    public String getMostRecentKey() {
            if(list.head == null)return "";
     return list.head.key;
    }
        public void evictLastUsedKey(){
           String keyToRemove = list.tail.key;
            cache.remove(keyToRemove);
            list.removeTail();
        }
        
            public void replaceKey(String key, int value){
            if(!this.cache.containsKey(key)){
                return;
            }
            cache.get(key).value = value;
        }
  }
    
    static class DoublyLinkedList{
        DoublyLinkedListNode head = null;
        DoublyLinkedListNode tail = null;
        
        public void setHead(DoublyLinkedListNode node){
            if(node == head) return;
            if(head == null){
                head = node;
                tail = node;
            } else if(head == tail){
                tail.prev = node;
                head = node;
                head.next = tail;
            } else {
                if(node == tail){
                    removeTail();
                    node.removeBindings();
                } else{
                    node.removeBindings();                  
                }
                    head.prev = node;
                    node.next = head;               
                  head = node;
                  
            }
        }
        public void removeTail(){
            if(tail == null) return;
            if(tail == head){
                head = null;
                tail = null;
                return;
            }
            tail = tail.prev;
            tail.next = null;
        }
        
    }
    static class DoublyLinkedListNode{
        DoublyLinkedListNode prev = null;
        DoublyLinkedListNode next = null;
        String key;
        int value;
        DoublyLinkedListNode(String key, int value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public void removeBindings(){
            if(prev!=null) prev.next = next;
            if(next!=null) next.prev = prev;
            prev = null;
            next = null;
        }
    }
  static class LRUResult {
    boolean found;
    int value;

    public LRUResult(boolean found, int value) {
      this.found = found;
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now what? Do you expect someone to read undocumented/uncommented source code? Did you yourself write the code you present above?

Comment: What is the connection to [tag:arrays] or [tag:hash-tables]?

Comment: @greybeard Yes I wrote it myself. And No don't expect you to read the entire source code. You should be able to navigate your way to the exact part which needs attention. SetHead() function. Infact, let's ignore the code that I have presented. The question is why is LRU cache not implemented with a doubly linked list with only two nodes?

Comment: @greybeard in LRU cache you typically use hash to retrieve values in O(1) time complexity. But you also need to maintain the "Least Recently Used" key and the "Most Recently Used Key"  where is where the doubly linked list comes into the picture. So basically head is your Most recently used node and tail is the least recently used node. If the max size is set to 3. Then the 4th entry will result in eviction of Least recently used node and addition of new node in its place.

Comment: @greybeard instead of doubly linked list, one could also use arrays. And use it's push and pop methods to get the LRU and MRU nodes. But that increases the time complexity because in arrays, shift() is not O(1) operatoin.

Comment: *[greybeard] should be able to navigate her way to the exact part which needs attention. `SetHead()` function* My web browser's text search did *not* navigate me to any definition of `SetHead()`.

Comment: (You seem to miss that `removeBindings()` not only plucks a node out from its list: it preserves the order information in `prev.next` and `next.prev`.)